# Trim leading and trailing spaces after "=" symbols in string c++

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I have a line which have data coming with "=" symbols. i need to ignore all white spaces before and after "=" symbol in my string
example:
input i have: "this is test = test1 and test1= test2"

output I am looking for:
 "this is test=test1 and test1=test2"

I have tried with istream ignore function and std::find function for string but not sure how can i remove trailing spaces unless a non-whites pace character occurs in the string. 
I found a similar question here but it is not answered.
:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265598/delimiter-is-getting-added-at-the-beginning-of-each-line-of-a-delimited-file-whi

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

If the other whitespace may be replaced by a single space, then you can read in all words from the string (std::cin <<), write them in a new string separated by a space and handle the needed tokens like "=" in this case by putting it in the string without spaces.  You will probably need some "spaceNeeded" flags to handle no space before and after the token.